# Namespace a dynamically loaded javascript file's contents

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

Is it possible to namespace a JavaScript file inserted dynamically?

I know that I can dynamically include a JavaScript file by creating a `script` tag and insert it into the DOM, but can this included file be namespaced? So, if the file has a function called `bar`, I would want access it through a namespace, say `foo`: i.e. `foo.bar()`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [CommonJS Modules/1.1](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) specifies only one way of doing it.

I've used it only with Node.js on server side, but I believe there are other libraries created to work with browser that are CommonJS compliant. Beware that there are multiple module specifications for server/browser (didn't dig into that yet).

Modules are written just like any other piece of javascript, the only addition is you export what you want to expose:

```
module.exports.bar = Bar;

function Bar() {
 // code
}
```

And the usage:

```
var foo = require('mymodule');

foo.bar();
```

What is actually done in the background, the whole code is wrapped into another function and exports are its properties.

Also, [Michael Bolin talked about similar problem in his talk about 'with' keyword at JSConf](http://a32.video2.blip.tv/11930008934667/Voodootikigod-JSConf2011MichaelBolin753.m4v?brs=658&bri=10.6).

Comment: CurlJS, requireJS support AMD modules which are similar and work out of the box on the browser. Tools like browserify allow you to create Modules/1.1 bundles.

Comment: I still haven't got around playing with this. One question though, does each included js file need to export the properties for the `require` to pick them up? If that is the case, how do I achieve namespacing when including third-party js file?

Comment: So how do you do it without using a library?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add a namespace to everything that is defined in that file while loading it dynamically, without modifying the file itself, the answer is no.