# Javascript namespaces and conditional inclusion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've some js files organized this way (see [source](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/tree/master/public/javascripts/gmaps4rails)):

- `gmaps4rails.base.js` : contains all the logic

  - `gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js` : contains functions
  - `gmaps4rails.bing.js` : contains functions with the same name as the previous file

So basically, `base` calls `createMarkers()` which is in both `googlemaps` and `bing`.

From now, I load only one among `gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js` and `gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js`, depending on the map API I need, so it works fine.

Now I'd like to be able to have all files loaded (and keep them separate) BUT of course only include the code of the desired maps API.

Basically I think about something like:

```
if desiredApi == "googlemaps"
   include GoogleMapsNameSpace content in BaseNameSpace
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a strategy pattern for the `createMarkers()` function?

Comment: Are those functions global? If yes, that's the issue right there. You don't want to have a script that contains a bunch of global functions that pollute the global namespace - instead, for each script you want to define **one** global name (the namespace), and then put everything (those functions) inside that namespace. If you had done it like so, you would have been able to include (and use) both scripts easily...

Comment: @whatgoodisaroad: I'm not familiar enough with js to answer this, I'll check the definition

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I do have two namespaces `Base` and `GoogleMaps` how could I merge one in the other?

Comment: @apneadiving It's not really a JS term, the strategy pattern is a generic [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Basically, it allows you to invoke any of a number of implementations via a unified interface.

Comment: @apnea Unfortunately, your scripts `googlemaps.js` and `bing.js` merely **augment** the existing `Gmaps4Rails` object - they do not create a new namespace. As a result, if you load both scripts, they will write / overwrite the same property names of the `Gmaps4Rails` object. What you could do is repeatedly load those scripts (whenever you need them) - that will trigger the overwrite (because they are executed again).

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yep, in my comment, I was simply anticipating a potential  solution. But is it possible to merge 2 namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to be able to use either the google maps API or the bing API or someother based on the user selection (or some other criteria)? For that, instead of trying to merge the correct API into your base object, why don't you just refer a 'mapService' from your base object and select the mapService based on the criteria you want?

Something like this:

```
Map = function(service, canvasId) {
    var mapService = MapServices[service];

    return {
        initialize: function() {
            var theMap = mapService.createMap();
            mapService.render(canvasId);
        }
// more functionality for your base object (that the outside world calls) goes here

    }
}

var MapServices = MapServices || {};

MapServices.google = {
  createMap: function() {},
  render: function(canvas) {
    $("#"+canvas).html("I'm a google map");
  },
  createMarker: function(args) {}
// all your map functionality goes here calling google specific functions
};

// this could be in a different js
MapServices.bing = {
  createMap: function() {},
  render: function(canvas) {
    $("#"+canvas).html("I'm a bing map");
  }, 
  createMarker: function(args) {},
// all your map functionality goes here calling bing specific functions
}

$(function() {
  var theMap = new Map("google", "theDiv");
  theMap.initialize();
});
```

Is this what you want to do?

Hope this helps

Comment: I ended up doing basic inheritance (my source codeis updated if you're curious). Whatever, your approach fits too!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for some kind of asynchronous loader. CommonJS has proposed [Modules 1.1](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) and the [Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) that do this. There are quite a few implementations of async loaders, as listed in [this Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqln2akPWiMIdERkY3J2OXdOUVJDTkNSQ2ZsV3hoWVE&hl=en#gid=2). Of which, a few of them are AMD-compliant, for example:

- curl.js http://github.com/unscriptable/curl
- RequireJS http://requirejs.org/
- bdLoad http://bdframework.org/bdLoad

This [blog entry](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2011/03/30/curl-js-yet-another-amd-loader/) has a nice discussion on this topic.

Also see this SO post: [Namespace a dynamically loaded javascript file's contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056081/dynamic-javascript-namespacing)

Comment: Thanks for these resources and +1. They have great added value. I finally ended up doing basic inheritance (source code updated if you're curious).